# Mutate a list in a list without for loop (python 3)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested

I am trying to mutate any instances of `" "` to print `-`: so I started by making a function that simply prints a list within a list on new lines:

```
def print_board(b):
    print("\n".join(map(lambda x:"".join(map(str, x)),b)))
```

ex:

```
>>> print_board([[1,2,3],[2,3,4,5],[2,3,4]]
123
2345
234
```

Then I tried to use this similar method to mutate each instance that `" "` was in the list to `-`:

```
def is_empty(b0):
    if b0 == " ":
        return "-"
    else:
        return b0

def empty_space(b):
    list(map(lambda x: list(map(is_empty, x)), b))#empty_space just mutates b

def check(b):
    _board = empty_space(b)
    return print_board(_board) #check just prints the mutated list b
```

and I would of wanted `check(b)` to do this for example:

```
>>> check([[" ",3,4],[5,6,3],[" ", " ", " "]])
-34
563
---
```

But I'm getting an error. I don't mind using recursion instead of map and lambda but I don't want to use for loops in any of these functions.

Comment: `empty_space` isn't returning the list. Also, `return print_board(_board)` will return `None`, you can just omit it altogether and do `print_board(_board)`.

Comment: I'm also referring to the function `empty_space`, as is, you aren't returning the list you're creating resulting in `None` getting returned. While we're at it, please specify the error you're getting and post the traceback Python provides.

Comment: Oh yes I want empty_space to return nothing thats why i made another definition to check that it was mutated properly

Comment: Ah right, you want to change it in place. My bad.

Comment: `return print_board(_board)` is always going to return `None` is that desirable?  also `print_board(_board)` is going to be `print_board(None)` always so not sure what you want there...

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think of that doesn't *explicitly* use a for-loop is to copy the new list to the reference you've got:

```
def empty_space(b):
    b[:] = map(lambda x: list(map(is_empty, x)), b)
```

this in effect changes the reference `b` passed to `empty_space` to have the values produced by the mapper, the `list` call is additionally not required since the right hand side can be any iterable.

You should also change `check` to be:

```
def check(b):
    empty_space(b)
    print_board(b)
```

since you aren't getting back any values.

Now this executes as required:

```
>>> check([[" ",3,4],[5,6,3],[" ", " ", " "]])
-34
563
---
```

---

`b[:]` does loop in the end (it must), I'm not really seeing why you feel the need to exclude `for` loops but I guess you must have your reasons.

Comment: Thanks! I get the changes to check but why would you put b[:] is that is the same thing as b? I didn't quick understand your explanation but I do get that now it would be referencing b[:] and not b the variable.

Comment: @pewnienewbie `b[:]` translates to "replace all values in `b` with the values on the right-hand side (the list created with `map` and `is_empty`)". Since `b` is a mutable reference (a list) the replacement is reflected in `check` afterwards.

Comment: Ohh I see. That is actually a really smart fix! Thanks again

Comment: Nice. Are `list` needed around `map`?

Comment: @EricDuminil nope, missed that, any iterable would do (so `map` objects apply). Nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion if you only work with 2D lists. I know you wrote you don't want to use any `for loop`, but `map` is nothing more than a disguised `for loop`. It also doesn't mutate the list.

So all you need is :

```
def check(rows):
    for row in rows:
        print "".join([str(x) for x in row]).replace(' ','-')

check([[" ",3,4],[5,6,3],[" ", " ", " "]])
# -34
# 563
# ---
```

If you really want to use `map`s :

```
def replace_char(char):
  return str(char).replace(' ', '-')

def replace_row(row):
  return "".join(map(replace_char, row))

def check(rows):
  print "\n".join(map(replace_row, rows))

check([[" ",3,4],[5,6,3],[" ", " ", " "]])
# -34
# 563
# ---
```